# TitledBorder on JTextField

Tags: java, swing, colors, border, jtextfield

When I put a `TitledBorder` around a `JTextField`, the entire background goes white, not just the area containing the text.

I think the problem is that the text field is a opaque component. Then, is it possible to put the title and enclosing box in the usual gray background while continuing to paint the text background white?

Answer (score 4):

I had hoped you could just use a `CompoundBorder`, but, because the fields actual background color is white, this doesn't have the desired effect.

Instead, you could wrap the field in a `JPanel` and apply the border to it, for example

[image: Border]

```
setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(field);
panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Hello"));
add(panel);
```

Now, if you don't want the field to have it's border, you can set it to `null`